# actionscript 3 event manager

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, event-handling

I have class EventManager with method:

```
public function addEvent(obj:IEventDispatcher, event:String, listener:Function, 
       useCapture:Boolean = false, priority:int = 0, 
       useWeakReference:Boolean = false):void 
{           
   obj.addEventListener(event, listener, useCapture, priority, useWeakReference);
   [here event is pushed in my stack]    
}
```

I want to do this:

```
public class CustomClass extends Sprite
{    
    public override function addEventListener(type:String, listener:Function, 
           useCapture:Boolean = false, priority:int = 0, 
           useWeakReference:Boolean = false):void
    {
        eventManager.addEvent(this, type, listener, useCapture, priority, useWeakReference);            
    }    
}
```

but in a result call stack is:

```
   customClass.addEventListener ->

   eventManager.addEvent ->

   customClass.addEventListener ->

   eventManager.addEvent ->

   customClass.addEventListener ->

   ...
```

and so on... because I invoke obj.addEventListener in eventManager.addEvent

Maybe can you give me a solution of this problem?

Comment: It looks like the code works as designed. What do you want it to do instead? Do you want `EventManager` to always call the "default" `addEventListener`? Why are you extending `addEventListener` and why does the `EventManager` class exist?

Comment: Because if obj is an instance of CustomClass then those 2 methods you posted will just continue to call each other recursively

Comment: ok. I want to override standart method 'addEventLIstener' of the EventDispatcher. My new method will call my service class EventManager.addEvent(). In this class I should invoke standart 'addEventLIstener'. But I don't know how do it. (EventManager keeps array of event listeners and thus I can remove all listeners of certain object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a recursive loop since you in event manager calls the addEventlistener function on object which calls the event manager etc... What you probably meant to do was to only store a reference to the object and the parameters inside event manager and not actually calling the addEventlistener-function from there.

Comment: Well, you only have two options: change the overridden function to not call EventManager or change EventManager to not call addEventlistener. You can change the function that is called from the overridden function to invoke EventManager.addEventlistenerNoCallback and then make that function do what the other does but without calling obj.addEventlistener...

Comment: So, you downgraded this since I tell you what you did wrong and offered a way of how you can solve it?

Comment: somebody anonymously downgraded my question and your answer. So I close question. (I voted up your answer because it was useful. Thanks)